# GStreamer stream audio and video via UDP to be able to playback on VLC

Tags: audio, video, udp, gstreamer, vlc

I am trying to stream audio and video via Gstreamer via UDP but playback on VLC only returns video without audio. Currently I am using a sample of Big Buck Bunny and have confirmed that it does have audio. I am planning to use Snowmix to feed media to Gstreamer output in the future.

Streaming from file source via UDP to playback on VLC I currently perform by:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=file:///home/me/files/Snowmix-0.5.1/test/big_buck_bunny_720p_H264_AAC_25fps_3400K.MP4 ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! queue ! udpsink host=230.0.0.1 port=4012 sync=true
```

which allows me to open a network stream in VLC on my Windows machine to receive packets and only plays video.

What am I missing from my command?

Comment: You just don't get audio stream from `uridecodebin`, and don't pass it to `mpegtsmux`. I'll try to find pipeline I'm using for the same task a little bit later, when will be on my linux box.

Comment: It seemed like `mpegtsmux` was the magic that allowed VLC to understand what was coming off of the stream, is it not?

Comment: `mpegtsmux` is thing that do mpeg-ts stream on output. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream

Comment: I read somewhere not long ago that VLC didn't like streams that weren't mpeg ts formats.

Answer (score 2):

As RSATom stated previously, the audio is missing from the pipeline.

The correct pipeline for video and audio is the next (tested with the same input file):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin name=uridec uri=file:///home/usuario/Desktop/map/big_buck_bunny_720p_H264_AAC_25fps_3400K.MP4 ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! video/x-h264 ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5014 sync=true uridec. ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! audio/mpeg ! queue ! mux.
```

Remember that in this case you're re-encoding all the content from the source video file, which means high CPU consumption. Other option would be to demux the content from the input file and mux again without encoding (using `h264parse` and `aacparse`).