# How to use gst-launch to streaming mp4 audio and video via rtp and play it?

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, gst-launch

I use these commands to send and recieve rtp data:

Send rtp data to UDP port 5000

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location = haizeiwang.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.1.101 port=5000
```

Receive rtp data from udp port 5000 and play it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96, ssrc=3394826012, timestamp-offset=2215812541, seqnum-offset=46353" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

But i can only get vedio(not very clear) , and there is no sound. Could i get vedio and audio at the same time?  Which elememnts should i use? What the commands should be?

Thank you.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505073/gstreamer-stream-audio-and-video-via-udp-to-be-able-to-playback-on-vlc#comment70222286_41505073

Answer (score 8):

**Sender** (audio+video):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin name=uridec uri=file:///C:\\video.mp4 ! videoconvert ! x264enc noise-reduction=10000 tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true ! mpegtsmux alignment=7 name=mux ! rtpmp2tpay ! queue ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 sync=true uridec. ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! audio/mpeg ! queue ! mux.
```

**Receiver** (audio+video, short version):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=udp://127.0.0.1:5000
```

**Receiver** (audio+video, long version):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! tsparse ! decodebin name=dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=true dec. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink sync=true
```

If you have access to **VLC** via cmd-line, you can play the stream with:

```
vlc rtp://@:5000
```

Or just go to VLC graphical interface to *Open Network Stream* (CTRL+N) and use the address I shared above.

Comment: Hello! Your examples works only on localhost for me. So if I try to broadcast source to another Clients I have an error: Could not find address...

Comment: I've used it in computers within the same LAN with no problems.

Comment: I try too, but  in my case it's not working. An error appears on the client side cmd. I dont know whats going on...

Comment: Firewall or antivirus turned on, maybe? Anyway, for network related problems I recommend going to [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) for help.

Comment: Today I try stream from my PC on Windp\ows 10 with turned off Virus and Thred protection an Brandmauer to Raspberri Pi II, I have the same error. But! If I stream only H.264 video using this command line: `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=d:/TestVideos/costarica.mp4 ! queue ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=ххх.ххх.х.ххх port=хххх`

Comment: Maybe in Client side caps parameters is needed?

Comment: vlc complains that SDP file is missing

Comment: Use the GUI as suggested on the end of the answer.

Comment: how would you use `filesrc location=` instead of uridecodebin in the sender command line?

Comment: The receiver short version works perfectly (no latency), vlc works (sometimes, and with 2sec latency, it seems its general to vlc), but the receiver long version runs but stays like stuck (no error, just a bunch of lines output on the console). What are its benefits? Any idea why it doesn't work?